# For which values of $k$ the general solution oscillate?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For which values of the parameter $k$ will the general solution of $$x''(t)-kx'(t)+7x(t)=0$$ oscillate as $t\to\infty$? I don't have idea how to do this?`

`

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The condition for a solution to be oscillated if it's neither converge or diverge. Therefore it must have pure imaginary eigenvalues. How to make the root of the following imaginary?
$$\lambda^2-k\lambda+7=0$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
Solutions looks like $\expo{\mu t}$ which yields $\mu^{2} - k\mu + 7 = 0$. Then
$$
\mu_{\pm} = {k \pm \root{k^{2} - 28} \over 2}
$$
When $k^{2} < 28\quad\imp\quad \verts{k} < 2\root{7}$, $\mu$ is a complex number:
$$
\mu = -\,\half\,k \pm \ic\omega
\quad\mbox{where}\quad \omega = \half\,\root{28 - k^{2}} \in {\mathbb R}
$$
The solutions are "oscillating" with ${\it\mbox{angular frequency}\ \omega}$: $\expo{\mu_{\pm}t} = \expo{-kt/2}\expo{\pm\ic\omega t}$